# Whats a better thing to use, when using long else if - C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, nested

What would be a good way to refactor this code to avoid the long nested else if statement? It takes quite a while, so it would be nice to turn it into a more simple function.

Below is my code:

```
if (data == "Januar")
{
    int cellnr = 1;
    searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
}
else if (data == "Februar")
{
    int cellnr = 2;
    searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
}
else if (data == "Marts")
{
    int cellnr = 3;
    searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
}
else if (data == "April")
{
    int cellnr = 4;
    searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
}
else if (data == "Marts")
{
    int cellnr = 5;
    searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
}
```

Comment: In your sample, `Marts` is checked twice, once it causes `cellnr` to be 3, and later it causes `cellnr` to be 5, is that a mistake?

Comment: Oh yeah - It is.. It goes +1 all the way down.

Comment: Hi @MatiasAabye! If one of those answers helped you, would you mind checking the gray ☑ at the left side of the answer in order to mark it as "accepted"? This would help you, the guy who answered and all the others with the same problem. Thank you! :)

Comment: Arh Ofcause - Was actually wondering why i couldn't mark the answer as "acceptet". It's done now :) Thanks for the advice - Have a nice day.

Comment: I posted an new answer based on your idea in your comments. I'll be happy if you take a look at that and find it helpful:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `switch` statement, but IMO that would still be quite verbose, I'd prefer a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> mapping = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"Januar", 1},
    {"Februar", 2},
    {"Marts", 3},
    {"April", 4},
};

searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), mapping[data]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create a static `Dictionary<string, int>` that maps those strings to the numbers you want, then simply look up `data` in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks - Decided to go with the Dictionary, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

As an other option, additional to initiative answer of Saeb, in your case probably there is no need to a dictionary, a simple list will be enough based on yourself idea in comments: Thinking about maybe making a array, and check data variable to that variable and then count +1 to cellnr each time - But not quite sure how to do it.

**Code:**

```
var dataList = new List<string> { "Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April" };
searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), dataList.IndexOf(data) + 1);
```

**Benefits:**

- Is shorter than dictionary.
- The dictionary approach fails if the key doesn't exits in the collection but the list approach handles it simply, it passes 0 value to your method and you can handle 0 in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a switch case instead

Comment: But a switch would still be quite long? Thinking about maybe making a array, and check data variable to that variable and then count +1 to cellnr each time - But not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Yes it depends. But in general instead of if/else/if , switch case is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `switch` statement, like already suggested, or you can create a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> mapping = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"Januar", 1},
    {"Februar", 2},
    ...
};
int cellnr = mapping[data];
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [`Switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement for better redability like

```
string data = somevariable;
switch (data)
{
    case "Januar":
      int cellnr = 1;
      searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
        break;
    case "Februar":
      int cellnr = 2;
      searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
        break;
    case "Marcs":
       int cellnr = 3;
       searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), cellnr);
        break;
    default:       
        break;
}
```

Comment: I can see the idea in Switch for the future, but in this case it seems like Dictionary does a better work, of making it more simply. My Else if is quite long. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Dictionary` way is definitely very appropriate here.  However, just to add more tools to your belt, another way is to use an `enum`:

```
// Setting January to 1 to match your setup.  I used English month names, so 
// you'd have to change that.
enum Months { January = 1, February, March, April, May, June, 
              July, August, September, October, November, December }

searchdata(row["CarNo"].ToString(), (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Months), data));
```

That way you don't have to worry about any sort of `switch` or `else-if` craziness.